# Better way to fill a dataframe column than iterrows - python + pandas

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe

I'm using python 3.7 and pandas 1.0.1

I'm trying to fill a column in my dataframe following the results of two previous columns.

I have a date column, an In column (which registers when an activity is starting) and an Out column (which registers when an activity is finished).

I need a Res column, which will register the overall duration of the activity.

First I have this simple dataframe:

```
    data = {'date':['2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-03','2020-01-04','2020-01-05','2020-01-06','2020-01-07','2020-08-01','2020-01-09','2020-01-10'],
            'in':[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
            'out':[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['date','in','out'])
    print(df)
```

The resulting dataframe is as follows:

```
         date  in  out
0  2020-01-01   0    0
1  2020-01-02   0    0
2  2020-01-03   1    0
3  2020-01-04   0    0
4  2020-01-05   0    0
5  2020-01-06   0    1
6  2020-01-07   0    0
7  2020-08-01   1    0
8  2020-01-09   0    1
9  2020-01-10   0    0
```

The result I'm trying to achieve is this:

```
         date  in  out  res
0  2020-01-01   0    0    0
1  2020-01-02   0    0    0
2  2020-01-03   1    0    1
3  2020-01-04   0    0    1
4  2020-01-05   0    0    1
5  2020-01-06   0    1    1
6  2020-01-07   0    0    0
7  2020-08-01   1    0    1
8  2020-01-09   0    1    1
9  2020-01-10   0    0    0
```

I was able to do it using iterrows:

```
    result = 0
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if (row['in']==1):
            result = 1
        elif (df['out'].shift(1)[index]==1):
            result = 0
        df.at[index,'res'] = result
```

But iterrows are not very time efficient when dealing with a very big dataframe.

How can I approach this problem in a better way?

Comment: Something like: `df['res'] = np.where(df['in'].eq(1), 1, np.where(df['out'].shift(1).eq(1), 1, 0), 0`?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I couldn't make it work... But the function .eq is something I'll try to use more often as I didn't know about it... Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try some simple arithmetic here:

```
t = df['in'] + df['out']  
t.cumsum().where(t.eq(0), 1).eq(1).astype(int)

0    0
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    1
6    0
7    1
8    1
9    0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hey... That is pretty clever... I would never come up witha a solution like that... Thanks a lot for the help.. :)